# Send parameters to a URL and get output from that page

Tags: php

I have 2 pages say `abc.php` and `def.php`. When `abc.php` sends 2 values [id and name] to `def.php`, it shows a message "Value received". Now how can I send those 2 values to `def.php` without using form in `abc.php` and get the "Value received" message from `def.php`? I can't use form because when user frequently visits the `abc.php` file, the script should automatically work and get the message "Value received" from `def.php`. Please see my example code:

`abc.php`:

```
 <?php 
  $id="123";
  $name="blahblah";
   //need to send the value to def.php & get value from that page
  // echo $value=Print the "Value received" msg from def.php;     
 ?>
```

`def.php`:

```
 <?php
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $name=$_GET['name'];
  if(!is_null($id)&&!is_null($name))
  {  echo "Value received";}
  else{echo "Not ok";}
 ?>
```

Is there any kind heart who can help me solve the issue?

Comment: get ans pls see the wimvds code below: $f = file_get_contents('http://your.domain/def.php?id=123&name=blahblah');
echo $f;

Answer (score 6):

First make up your mind : do you want GET or POST parameters.

Your script currently expects them to be GET parameters, so you can simply call it (provided that URL wrappers are enabled anyway) using :

```
$f = file_get_contents('http://your.domain/def.php?id=123&name=blahblah');
```

To use the curl examples posted here in other answers you'll have to alter your script to use $_POST instead of $_GET.

Comment: WOW...just a single line code and solve all of my problems..many thanks wimvds.Also many thanks all the people who guide me to solve..thx bro

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the [examples page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) of php.net:

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com/abc.php");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec( $ch );

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close( $ch );
```

Edit: To send parameters

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('var1=foo', 'var2=bar'));
```

Comment: How i send the parameters to def.php?could you pls help??

Comment: thx for effort..but value not received on def.php and don't show the value..pls help

Answer (score 3):

You can try without cURL (I havent tried though):

Copy pasted from : [POSTing data without cURL extension](http://simas.posterous.com/posting-data-without-curl-extension)

```
// Your POST data
$data = http_build_query(array(
    'param1' => 'data1',
    'param2' => 'data2'
));

// Create HTTP stream context
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $data
    )
));

// Make POST request
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, $context);
```

Comment: thanks trix, but when i run the script then it's showing "Not Ok" that mean code does not working..could you pls help...

Comment: Dear trix,pls give some time for me..i think  we are near to solve the problem.But the response is showing "Not ok".Please see my code and suggest me how i can get the value "Value received";

Comment: replace $_GET with $_POST in def.php, also check wimvds answer

Answer (score 1):

use [CURL](http://no.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html).

Comment: could u pls give and example to do it?

Comment: Yeroon copy pasted an example.

Comment: thx for helping me...but how i send value to def.php and get the output from def.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$method = 'GET'; //change to 'POST' for post method
$url = 'http://localhost/browse/';
$data = array(
    'manufacturer' => 'kraft',
    'packaging_type' => 'bag'
    );

if ($method == 'POST'){
//Make POST request
    $data = http_build_query($data);
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "$method",
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $data)
        )
    );
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
else {
// Make GET request
    $data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
    $response = file_get_contents($url."?".$data, false);
}
echo $response;
?>
```

get inspired by [trix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314566/1700191), I decided to extend that code to cater for both GET and POST method.